# Mysql database repair

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had few problems with my server (hosting full, forgot mysql password etc.) Now that everything is fine when I check phpmyadmin I only have information_schema
/ mysql / performance_schema/phpmyadmin database available.

However I would like to get access to my database which is at /etc/mysql/mydb any idea how can I get access to it through phpmyadmin?  mydb folder contains only .ibd + .frm files

Comment: I did find the way to see the database into my phpmyadmin now the problem is when I try to access I see the following error message :  #1033 - Incorrect information in file: './my_db/s_code_info.frm'

Comment: Have you modified that `.frm` file or its permissions in any way?

Comment: Is there anything useful in the `mysqld.err` log file?

Comment: @RickJames I did not change anything into the .frm file. but I moved it from one hosting to another hosting.

Comment: Were the MySQL versions the _same_ on both hostings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In moving tables (or databases) from one machine, you must follow these rules.  There may be exceptions where the migration will work, but it sounds like they don't apply to your situation.

- Same version of MySQL/MariaDB (or "close enough")
- If copying files, move the *entire* tree, *not* just one table or database.

The only safe way to migrate from one server to another is to dump and reload (`mysqldump`, `XtraBackup`, etc).

In particular, a simple InnoDB table involves 3 things (pre-8.0):

- `.ibd` file containing the data and index(es).  This exists only if the table was created when `innodb_file_per_table=ON`.
- `.frm` schema.
- Some other info in the communal `ibdata1`.

See also "transportable tablespaces".  They may provide a way to copy part of a dataset from one machine to another.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very nonstandard. The typical way to copy a database, script, or table from one host to another is with an export script. If you still have access to the original source I recommend executing mysqldump then restoring the database from the file generated by the mysqldump command. You can also use the export wizard under the "management" tab in the MySQL Workbench sidebar. I believe there is a similar export wizard in PHPMyAdmin as well.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/export-database-using-phpmyadmin